# PrimeNg remove multiselect label

Tags: javascript, css, angular, frontend, primeng

I'm trying to remove multiselect label of selected items ,And replace it with static defaultLabel ,,

What Its show
[image]

I tryed this one :

```
    .p-multiselect-label {
    visibility: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

It's remove any selected label but when the selected label is increased there is white space is increased too & i can't add defaultLabel whene there are any selectd item!

What I want
[image]

Comment: Read the [docs](https://primefaces.org/primeng/multiselect). Looks for `displaySelectedLabel` and see if that will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for response,, I already add [displaySelectedLabel]="true" , but it's not showing when there are some selection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the selected items template:

```html
<p-multiSelect #multiSelect defaultLabel="Select a city">
  <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItems">
    {{ multiSelect.defaultLabel }}
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-qmdeyp?file=src/app/app.component.html)